# Why does python think my variable is empty?

Tags: python, concatenation, string-concatenation

Before I put in the 2 if statements on the 3rd code block, I was getting pretty much the same error, that it can't concatenate a str and a Nonetype.

However when I uncomment the print statement in my 3rd if statement, it prints out a list of urls with paths.

I've also tried this on other websites it's not just this one that isn't working.

here is my traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkcrawler.py", line 24, in <module>
    newurl = "http://" + b1 + b2
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkcrawler.py", line 24, in <module>
     newurl = "http://" + b1 + b2
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

I only get two every time that I run it.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import traceback
import urlparse
import mechanize

url = "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html"
br = mechanize.Browser()
urls = [url]
visited = [url]

while len(urls)>0:
    try:
        br.open(urls[0])
        urls.pop(0)
        for link in br.links():
            newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url,link.url)
            b1 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).hostname
            b2 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).path

            newurl = "http://"+b1+b2

            if newurl not in visited and urlparse.urlparse(url).hostname in newurl:
                urls.append(newurl)
                visited.append(newurl)
                #print newurl
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        urls.pop(0)
print visited
```

Comment: either `b1` or `b2`  (or both) is `None`. You need to account for it somehow.

Comment: It is probably just printing stuff until newurl = "http://"+b1+b2 fails because one of b1 or b2 is None.

Comment: There is either no host name or no path, apparently.

Comment: This is not the code you're running. It would be better to post the exact function. The error in your real code happens in the `newurl = ...` line, but in what you posted that's impossible - it would raise an exception on either `len(b1)` or `len(b2)`.

Comment: yeah your right I get an exception b1 now

Answer (score 0):

Either `b1` or `b2` is `None`. To solve this, check if `b1` and `b2` are empty or `None` and restructure your code as such:

```
b1 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).hostname
b2 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).path

if b1 and b2:
    newurl = "http://"+b1+b2
    if newurl not in visited and urlparse.urlparse(url).hostname in newurl:
        urls.append(newurl)
        visited.append(newurl)
        #print newurl
else:
    urls.pop(0)
```